# How to stop a sound Smooth in OpenAL

Tags: ios, objective-c, openal

I have too many sound to play in OpenAL，and the number of source is too much, Sometimes I have to stop some sources use function alSourceStop.but it often produce broken sound (sonic boom),How to avoid this phenomenon?

Answer (score 2):

Note: I am not an iOS developer and just showing a solution which I would have used on any other platform.

You can implement sound fade out yourself by gradually changing source's gain over some period of time after you decided to stop it.
Basically, that's what you have to do

```
float t = now - stopTime;
float d = 10
if(t > d)
   //Stop sound and delete source
else 
    alSourcef(source, AL_GAIN, originalGain * (1F - t / d))
```

In this pseudocode `originalGain` is the gain of the source without fadeout

`now` - current time
`stopTime` - moment when you decided to stop source
`10` - duration of fadeout

By using these values you can linearly interpolate between between full gain and 0 and prevent broken sound effect.

Comment: Thanks very much, I will try it in my project